# Mongodb period of time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, nosql

I would like to have some help with mongodb/mongoose, since I'm a bit stuck here.

I'm making an employee hour logging web application with MEAN stack and I have no idea how to create periods in Mongodb/Mongoose every two weeks.

E.g. start date: 4.7, end date: 17.7 and when current date turns to 18.7 it would create new document with start date: 18.7 and end date: 31.7 etc.

My schema is currently as follows (I'm going to add more info to this later on):

```
var payPeriodSchema = new Schema ({
hoursInPayPeriod: {
  type: Number,
  default: 0,
  required: true
},
payPeriodStartDate: {
  type: Date,
  required: true
},
payPeriodEndDate: {
  type: Date,
  required: true
},
isPaid: {
  type: Boolean,
  default: false,
  required: true
}
}, {
timestamps: true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple cronjob will do the job. I'd put this task in a separate project, apart from your main node server.